# using a switch statement in a while loop c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement

EDITED
i have this project for a lab, the requirments are that we use a loop, we need temp to go from 60-100 and humidity form 40-100% and then get the THI ( temp humidity index), i originally wanted to make a while loop and have rh ++ and temp++ then a switch stament with both variables but it did not want to work with 2 variables so i decided to have a while loop and switch inside a switch statement inside a while loop which ik is not readable, i would make methods for everything else but i need to use a loop

```
using System;

namespace _1012Lab3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // calculate THI(Temp- 0.55(1-Relative Humidity)(Temp -58))
            //relative humidity range 40% - 100%
            //temp range 60F - 100F
            //increments of 10
            // make a method for the formula?
            //THI = Tdb – [0.55 – (0.55 x RH/100)] x (Tdb – 58)
            //create loop that goes up in incremets of 10
            //while temp<10 
            // rh is 0-1 so for 60% humidity  60/100=0.6
            // test example works temp 60 ,RH 50(0.5) answer is 59.45
            //temp ranges 60,70,80,90,100
            //Rh ranges 40,50,60,70,80,90,100
            double temp = 0;
            double THI=0;
            double rh=0;
            while (temp <=100)
            {
                temp++;
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 60:
                       while(rh<=100)
                        {
                            rh++;
                        }
                            switch(rh)
                            {
                            case 40:
                                Console.Write("yes");
                                Console.Write(rh);
                                Console.Write(temp);
                                Console.WriteLine($" case 40the temp is{temp}rh is{rh}and thi is {THI}");
                                break;

                            case 50:
                                THI = Thi(temp, rh);
                                Console.WriteLine($" case 50the temp is{temp}rh is{rh}and thi is {THI}");
                                break;
                            
                            case 60:
                                
                                break;

                            case 70:
                                
                                break;
                            
                            case 80:
                               
                                break;
                            
                            case 90:
                                
                                break;
                            
                            case 100:
                                
                                break;
                        }
                        
                        break;
                   
                    case 70:
                       
                        break;
                    
                    case 80:
                        
                        break;
                    
                    case 90:
                        
                        break;
                  
                    case 100:
                        
                        break;


                }




            }
        }
        
        static double Thi(double temp1, double RH1)
        {
            double RH2 = (RH1 / 100);
            double THI = temp1 - 0.55 * (1 - RH2) * (temp1 - 58);
            return THI;
        }
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: `switch(rh)` is not inside the while loop, it is after it. `rh` will always be `101+` when it hits `switch(rh)`.

Comment: If you find yourself writing long switch statements like this on nondescript numbers you are doing something wrong

Comment: Please review [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question accordingly. Currently there are 2 `while` and 2 `switch` statements shown making it quite confusing what you have problem with (and not really clarifying what you want to achieve). Note that it may be good idea to debug code before asking... Ideally you example should show only branches that you expect to be executed and no extra empty `case` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to calculate the `thi` value for each possible combination of `temp` and `rh`, you can achieve that in a nested `for` loop that iterates over only the relevant `temp` and `rh` values:

```
int tempMin = 60;
int tempMax = 100;
int tempStep = 10;

int rhMin = 40;
int rhMax = 100;
int rhStep = 10;

double thi;

for (int temp = tempMin; temp <= tempMax; temp += tempStep)
{
    for (int rh = rhMin; rh <= rhMax; rh += rhStep)
    {
        thi = Thi(temp, rh);

        Console.WriteLine($"The temp is {temp}, rh is {rh} and thi is {thi}");
    }
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYobDO).

Answer (score 0):

When you get your code with lots of levels, it's recomended simplify:

```
double temp = 0;
double THI = 0;
double rh = 0;
while (temp <= 100)
{
    ManageTemp(ref temp, ref rh, ref THI);
}
```

And move the code into other methods, reducing the cyclomatic complexity:

```
private void ManageTemp(ref double temp, ref double rh, ref double THI)
{
    temp++;
    Console.WriteLine(temp);

    switch (temp)
    {
        case 60: ManageTemp60(temp, ref rh, ref THI); break;
        case 70: ManageTemp70(temp, ref rh, ref THI); break;
        case 80: ManageTemp80(temp, ref rh, ref THI); break;
        case 90: ManageTemp90(temp, ref rh, ref THI); break;
        case 100: ManageTemp100(temp, ref rh, ref THI); break;
    }
}

private void ManageTemp60(double temp, ref double rh, ref double THI)
{
    while (rh <= 100)
    {
        rh++;

        switch (rh)
        {
            case 40:
                Console.Write("yes");
                Console.Write(rh);
                Console.Write(temp);
                Console.WriteLine($" case 40the temp is{temp}rh is{rh}and thi is {THI}");
                break;

            case 50:
                THI = Thi(temp, rh);
                Console.WriteLine($" case 50the temp is{temp}rh is{rh}and thi is {THI}");
                break;

            case 60:
                break;

            case 70:
                break;

            case 80:
                break;

            case 90:
                break;

            case 100:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You may also create a class like:

```
public class TempData
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public double THI { get; set; }
    public double rh { get; set; }
}
```

And simplify the work with the parameters:

```
var tempData = new TempData();
while (tempData.temp <= 100)
{
    ManageTemp(tempData);
}

private void ManageTemp(TempData tempData)
{
    tempData.temp++;
    //...

    switch (tempData.temp)
    {
        case 60: ManageTemp60(tempData); break;
        //...
    }
}

private void ManageTemp60(TempData tempData)
{
    while (tempData.rh <= 100)
    {
        tempData.rh++;
        //...
    }
}
```

In this way you can avoid lots of problems and get a more readable code.